# Extracting custom "data" tags using BeautifulSoup (python)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Scraping HTML that looks like this:

```html
<div class="resultRow" data-unix="1528542937" id="resultRow1">
<div class="resultRow" data-unix="1528542937" id="resultRow2">
<div class="resultRow" data-unix="1528542937" id="resultRow1">
```

How do I extract the value of the data-unix field?

Do I have to use REGEXP for this or is there a better method?

```
for tmp in soup.findAll('div', {'class':'resultRow'}):
      x = tmp.find(re.compile('/data-unix="(.*)"/'))
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have a look at a HTML / XML reading classes (like HTMLParser and xml.dom) and see what you can do with attributes and its attribute values

Answer (score 1):

Per your question about moving Ajax1234's answer inside a loop:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = """
<div class="resultRow" data-unix="1528542937" id="resultRow1">
<div class="resultRow" data-unix="1528542937" id="resultRow2">
<div class="resultRow" data-unix="1528542937" id="resultRow1"> 
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')

final_results = []

for tmp in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'resultRow'}):

    final_results.append(tmp['data-unix'])

print final_results

['1528542937', '1528542937', '1528542937']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the builtin `__getitem__` method declared for `BeautifulSoup` objects dictionary-style:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
s = """
<div class="resultRow" data-unix="1528542937" id="resultRow1">
<div class="resultRow" data-unix="1528542937" id="resultRow2">
<div class="resultRow" data-unix="1528542937" id="resultRow1"> 
"""
final_results = [i['data-unix'] for i in soup(s, 'html.parser').find_all('div', {'class':'resultRow'})]
```

Output:

```
['1528542937', '1528542937', '1528542937']
```

Comment: Is it possible to move it inside the resultRow loop? If so, what is the syntax?